# Optimal prime/semiprime/composite test not working for small numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

There is an algorithm to check is a number prime/semiprime/composite.

Pseudo code:

```
    Input a number N and if N – 1 and N + 1 is not divisible by 6 then the number N is Not Prime. else it is prime or semi-prime
    If n-1 or n+1 is divisible by 6 then iterate in the range(sqrt(N) + 1, N) and find a pair (p, q) such that p*q = N by below formula:

    p = i - sqrt(i*i - N)
    q = n/p
    where i = index in range(sqrt(N) + 1, N)

    If p*q = N then the number N is semi prime, else it is prime
```

But it fails for some semi-prime number.
For 6 it gives composite instead of semi-prime.
For 10 it gives composite instead of semi-prime.
But for 7894561 it gives semi-prime as should.

Is there optimal algorithm to deduce is a number prime/semi-prime/composite?
Perhaps I misuse the algorithm and don't understand it's limitations?
It is explained that number should be greater than 300. But why 300?
Does it always work properly for numbers greater than 300?
Please advise.

Below is the C++ implementation of the approach:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;
  
void prime(long n)
{
    int flag = 0;
  
    // checking divisibilty by 6
    if ((n + 1) % 6 != 0 && (n - 1) % 6 != 0) 
    {
        cout << ("Composite") << endl;
    }
    else
    {
  
        // breakout if number is perfect square
        double s = sqrt(n);
        if ((s * s) == n) 
        {
            cout<<("Semi-Prime")<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            long f = (long)s;
            long l = (long)((f * f));
  
            // Iterating over to get the
            // closest average value
            for (long i = f + 1; i < l; i++)
            {
  
                // 1st Factor
                long p = i - (long)(sqrt((i * i) - (n)));
  
                // 2nd Factor
                long q = n / p;
  
                // To avoid Convergence
                if (p < 2 || q < 2) 
                {
                    break;
                }
  
                // checking semi-prime condition
                if ((p * q) == n)
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
  
                // If convergence found
                // then number is semi-prime
                else 
                {
  
                    // convergence not found
                    // then number is prime
                    flag = 2;
                }
            }
  
            if (flag == 1) 
            {
                cout<<("Semi-Prime")<<endl;
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
  
                cout<<("Prime")<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
      
    prime(8179);
    prime(7894561);
    prime(90000000);
    prime(841);
    prime(22553);
    prime(1187);
}
```

I used [the article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-is-prime-semi-prime-or-composite-for-very-large-numbers/).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How to? What should I remove? Should I rephrase the title?

Comment: A semiprime is composite. It is the product of two (possibly equal) primes.

Comment: Checking whether a number is a semiprime is as difficult as factoring it. I suggest the following procedure : $(1)$ If the given number is a perfect square, then it is a semiprime if and only if the square root is prime $(2)$ Test the given number. If it is prime , you are done (no semiprime). $(3)$ Search for a small prime factor. (continuation in next comment)

Comment: If you have found one you are done (we have a semiprime if and only if the cofactor is prime). Otherwise use the usual prime factorization tools to find any prime factor , which is already enough. Without finding a prime factor, you cannot decide whether you have a semiprime, unless I understood a recent statement right that elliptic curves can detect semiprimes without actually applying the factorization. But I might have misunderstood something, and this would be extremely astonishing, if it would be possible.

Comment: Fairly easy to create semiprimes of small magnitude.